# Is the loss in keras in percentage?

Tags: theano, keras

I am trying to implement VGGNet-16 for depth map prediction from single image. In the training the RMSE loss comes out to be 0.1599.

That loss value, is it in percentage or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want a percentage of a correctly classified data you can look at a value of accuracy.

Definition of RMSE from Wikipedia:

> The root-mean-square deviation (RMSD) or root-mean-square error (RMSE) is a frequently used measure of the differences between values (sample and population values) predicted by a model or an estimator and the values actually observed.

It's always non-negative, and values closer to zero are better.